# Number of values in a parameterized google test

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm using google test with a parameterized test class. I provide a list of strings to the testcases and I know that I can access each individual value using `GetParam()`. Additionally I would like to ensure that all flags are covered, so I would need to know if the number of flags in the testcase is the same as the number of flags available.

Something like this.

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Actions, TestActions
    , ::testing::Values
    (
        "FLAG1"
        , "FLAG2"
        , "FLAG3"
    )
);

TEST_F(TestActions, ActionCount)
{
    // Check if a testcase was forgotten
    EXPECT_EQ(gActions.size(), ParamCount());
}

TEST_P(TestActions, ActionEnabled)
{
    string action = GetParam();
    ... do something here with param.
}

TEST_P(TestActions, ActionDisabled)
{
    string action = GetParam();
    ... do something here with param.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual with such questions I didn't find a solution until I posted this question and shortly after found a solution anyway.

The basic idea to solve this I got from this question and it's answers. [Google Tests ValuesIn with a global vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837284/google-tests-valuesin-with-a-global-vector)

So for completness in hope that others may find it usuefull I post my solution here.

```
static std::vector<std::string> getKnownActions()
{
    std::vector<std::string> actions = { "FLAG1", "FLAG2", "FLAG3"};
    return actions;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Actions, TestActions, ::testing::ValuesIn(getKnownActions()));

TEST_F(TestActions, ActionCount)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(gActions.size(), getKnownActions().size());
}
```